# Java Program not Accessing images properly

Tags: java, image, file

I am making a game in java which involves drawing images to a frame. When I attempt to draw the images, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1348)
    at main.Game.<init>(Game.java:57)
    at main.Game.main(Game.java:319)
```

Why am I getting this? Here is the code for the area I am accessing the files:

```
try {
    playerImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/player.png"));
    bulletImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/bullet.png"));
    enemyImage = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/enemy.png"));

    highScoreReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/files/HIGH_SCORE.txt"));
    highScoreWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/files/HIGH_SCORE.txt"));

} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is a picture of the file directories:

[image]

Am I coding the directory wrong? Am I not grabbing the image correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Is the "s", you have "resour'C'es" and the folder is "resour'S'es"

Answer (score 0):

Your resource folder is named `resourses` but your code is calling from `"resources/player.png"`.

Comment: thats because player.png is the file name

Comment: I mean that in the image you linked of the file directories the resource folder is spelled resour**s**es